# How to trigger an application in a mobile on receiving an sms?

Tags: java-me, mobile

I want to trigger a inbuild application in the mobile on receiving a sms. I have codes to read a sms from a mobile but after reading that sms the mobile must automatically trigger an application.

Is it possible to do that? If yes tell me a good idea to trigger another application on receiving the sms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is pretty standard solution for doing this using push registry. Here is [the link for it](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/03/start-application-using-pushregistry.html).